Mariadb, installed via brew, does not run on startup
I have installed MariaDB via brew and each time I restart my computer I need to start it manually by
brew services start mariadb@10.5

Also I cannot find mariadb listed in the "Login Items" in Settings > General
How do I make mariadb appear in the "Login Items"?
Thank you in advance.

I believe the problem was caused because the service was configured to start by "root" and this was competing with a setting that told it to start as a user. I have stopped the service using sudo
sudo brew services stop mariadb@10.5

and restarted the computer. This seems to have fixed it, as the mysqld_safe item has now appeared in the "Login Items" list in Settings > General.
